# Pandas group by find minimum of column if it doesn't exist return NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,3,2], 'year': ['2020', '2014', '2002', '2020', '2016', '2014'], 'e': [True, False, True, True, False, True]})

df.info()
id  year      e
  1  2020   True
  1  2014  False
  1  2002   True
  2  2020   True
  3  2016  False
  2  2014   True
```

And I want to find the minimum year of each id where *e* is True, if there isn't any True in *e* for that id return NaN. The end result would be:

```
id  year
1   2002
2   2014
3   NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filter before `groupby` and `reindex` back

```
s = df.loc[df.e].groupby('id').year.min().reindex(df.id.unique()).reset_index()

s
Out[307]: 
   id  year
0   1  2002
1   2  2014
2   3   NaN
```

---

Or convert to `Categorical`

```
df['id'] = pd.Categorical(df['id'])
df.loc[df.e].groupby('id').year.min()
Out[309]: 
id
1    2002
2    2014
3    None
Name: year, dtype: object
```